# Error al iniciar Android Studio en Win10

Tags: android-studio

Estoy teniendo un error al querer iniciar mi Android Studio. Ya he modificado las variables de entorno sin embargo el error sigue apareciendo.
El error es el siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haga lo siguiente:

1) Versión de JDK instalada 1.8 como se sugiere en [este link](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html).

2) Establecer la ruta de Java

3) Descargue la última versión de Android Studio desde [aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), descargue el que tiene SDK e Imagen del sistema

4) Al instalar Android Studio, ejecute la configuración haciendo clic con el botón derecho y seleccione `Ejecutar como administrador`.

5) Durante la instalación, asegúrese de que cuando la configuración solicite la ruta de acceso de Android Studio y SDK, la ruta no contenga ningún espacio blanco.

> - Vea aquí como confirugar las [Variables de entorno para la
>     instalación de Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/8933039)
> - Establezca sus variables de ruta en consecuencia [Android Studio -
>     Cómo cambiar la ruta del SDK de Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582792/8933039)

También puede probar lo suiguiente:

Si durante la instalación encontró su JDK, y no fue capaz de encontrarlo cuando intentaba abrirlo, agregue una variable  de entorno `JDK_HOME` a las variables de su sistema. Debe contener la ruta al directorio `ROOT` de su `JDK`, es decir `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\...`

> Por cierto, vale la pena notar que si está en `x64`, necesita apuntar a un `JDK` de `32` bits porque la aplicación es de 32 bits.